# Element to take remaining height of viewport

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

Please consider this style:

```
.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  .logo-pane {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .user-actions {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

What I want to achieve is that the `content` element will take the remaining height of the viewport, but it takes only his content height.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo-pane">Logo</div>
    <div class="user-actions">User Actions</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ronenl/pen/LZGZZX)

Comment: please provide the html code ?

Comment: ?? your code &  codepen just does what you ask for

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is the surrounding `.root`. You have to increase the height of the `.root` to the remaining space. So you have to set the `height:100vh;` on `.root`. Try the following solution:

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items:stretch;
  align-content:stretch;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.logo-pane {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
.user-actions {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.content {
  flex-grow:1;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo-pane">Logo</div>
    <div class="user-actions">User Actions</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why giving `height: 100%` to the root is not enough?

Comment: @ronen because % value need a reference from css to be able to calculate something. height:100%; only works for HTML . so .root{height:100%} needs to inherit a reference to be something . so you need to do html {height:100%} then it is usable for  body {height:100%}  and from here .root will apply those 100% from viewport . value cascaded from wiewport/html via body to .root has now the value of the viewport height ---. hope this was clear :)

Answer (score 2):

```
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `:root` to `100vh` (100% of the viewport height) instead `100%`

Answer (score 1):

I think your misunderstanding what flex does. Flex is used to align its children, not to fill a viewport. Heres another solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/rob_primacy/1wnpr50s/

```
<div class="root">
 <div class="header">
  <div class="logo-pane">Logo</div>
  <div class="user-actions">User Actions</div>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
```

and the css

```
.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
 }
.user-actions {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.logo-pane {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
 left: 8px;
 right: 8px;
}
```

Comment: nop, flex can fill any container that has a width or height set. flex:1; on its own does the trick. if a few children, then flex:1; (to them) will spray then evenly to start with, filling the whole container. the op does: height:100vh on flex container, that is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add

1. `height: 100%` to `html, body`
2. add height to `20%` for root div
3. add height to `80%` for content div

will solve your problem

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wuoag955/)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>

<style type="text/css">
body{
margin:0;
}
.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  .logo-pane {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .user-actions {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: pink;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: fixed;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="root">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo-pane">Logo</div>
    <div class="user-actions">User Actions</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
</div>
</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: .root {height:100%} ?? 100% of what ? body has no height defined :) in your code

Comment: .root i defined 100% of height then only .content will take .header+remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

Your codepen linked works fine. I do not understand where you get stuck.

You could basicly build your template from 2 containers :example with `header` and `main`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;/* or just : 100vh; for body only */
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* width and margin:auto is avalaible */
}
header {
  /*  height: 50px;or do not set any and let grow from its content */
  background: gray;
}

main {
  flex: 1;/* will fill up all space left */
  background: lightblue;
  /* overflow:auto; optionnal if you do not want html to scroll and keep header fixed */
}
```

```html
  <header>
    whatever <br/> sizes me
  </header>
  <main> 
    content
  </main>
```

Make it simple to start with :)